# sql where condition

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm using MySQL 5.5 and have a table that has two columns `user_1`, `user_2`.

I want to `SELECT` every instance where the value of `user_1` and the value of `user_2` are the same at least two or more times.

So if a dataset has for instance:

`user_1 | user_2
 foo    | bar
 foo    | xzy
 abc    | der
 foo    | xzy
 abc    | der
 abc    | def`

in this particular case, we'd have two matches, and that's where `user_1` is equal to `foo` and `user_2` is equal to `xzy` as well as where `user_1` is equal to `abc` and `user_2` is equal to `der`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `group by` and `having`:

```
select user_1, user_2
from t
group by user_1, user_2
having count(*) >= 2;
```